# How to configure MasterPage to Inherit class file

Tags: c#, master-pages

I have a Master page which needs to inherit from a class (MasterPage2.cs) stored inside "App_Web_yht1mma2" folder.

In the master page, I have set the code as:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="MasterPage2,App_Web_yht1mma2" %>
```

When I debug this page, I receive the following error:

> Parser Error
>       Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load the assembly 'App_Web_yht1mma2'. Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="MasterPage2,App_Web_yht1mma2" %>
Line 2:
Line 3:

Source File: /MasterPage.master    Line: 1
```

Kindly advise me on how to correct this error.

Comment: Build the solution, fix the compilation errors.

Comment: Thanx...the error indicates that it cant load the assembly.

Comment: Did you build your project and check the compiler errors?

Comment: Yes I did and besides the warnings, I still get this error "Parser Error Message: Could not load the assembly 'App_Web_yht1mma2'. Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page.
"

Comment: The parser error you get is the end result. You need to fix the underlying cause so your `App_Web_yht1mma2` compiles. In order to do so, you need to fix the compile-time errors and warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help but I managed to figure it out through assistance from a friend.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage2" %>
```

or

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MainMasterPageWeb.Master.cs"
Inherits="App_Web_yht1mma2.MasterPage2" %>
```

Both ways are possible solutions